# How to pipe `terraform state show` outputs to a bash variable?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a bash script where I'm trying to isolate a string of the form z="y=x" so that I can use `eval $z` in order to create a env variable `y` with value 'x'. Here's my code:

```
xxx=$(terraform state show aws_s3_bucket.prod_bucket | grep website_endpoint | sed 's/ //g')
echo $xxx
>>>website_endpoint="my-site.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
eval $xxx
>>>-bash: website_endpoint=my-site.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com: command not found
```

What perplexes me about the failure of this code is that I do something very similar to convert the contents of a `.env` file to working environment variables:

```
cmd=$(sed -ne '/^#/d; /^export / {p;d}; /.*=/ s/^/export / p' .env)
eval $cmd     ### works!
```

Why does the latter work but not the prior?

Edit: Now that I've identified the problem as being with terraform and not bash, I've changed the title to reflect that

Comment: It's safer and simpler to use `declare` rather than `eval` for this use case.

Comment: Please don't add random text to the shell output. `>>>` in the string would result in a completely different error message.

Comment: @l0b0 I just added ">>>" to this post to indicate that this line shows an output message and not another command

Comment: @Magnus. `eval` does not work because  your `xxx` shell variable is a string that does not contain a command that can be executed - hence the `command not found` error message.

Comment: @Magnus I understand the motivation, but the added text makes the question *wrong.* If you don't show us **exactly** what you're seeing it's basically impossible to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I figured out what was going on here. The `terraform state show` command will, by default, include escape characters for color, emboldening, etc. Unfortunately, these characters do not show up at all in the terminal because, oddly, they seem to switch off any visible effect whenever it actually goes to print anything! So in my case, the $xxx looked like this:

```
[1m[0mwebsite_endpoint[0m[0m="magnus-misc-v2.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
```

... and since `[0m` removes all formatting and colors, I was given no visual clue that this jazz was in there disrupting my `eval`-ing. So the fix in my case was to use the `terraform state show -no-color` flag. Not really a bash issue, rather, some confusing stuff in the terraform CLI.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have a string which represents a [string](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048#The_problem_with_declare) variable assignment, a safe and simple way to perform that assignment is `declare` (and [Using More Quotes™](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)):

```
$ xxx='website_endpoint="my-site.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com"'
$ declare "$xxx"
$ echo "$website_endpoint"
"my-site.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
```

Comment: What you have here works, but when xxx is the result of the `$(...)` expression in my question then `declare "$xxx"` results in `-bash: declare: \`: not a valid identifier`. So whatever xxx is here, it doesn't seem to be a straightforward "string variable" as you put it. (However, I'm told that bash variables don't have 'types', so I'm pretty confused at this point.)